# Xamarin GestureRecognizer while holding

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have a frame gesture recognizer with a tap gesture recognizer. Whenever I click on the frame and I release, something happens. However, I want something to happen aswell when I am holding down the frame.

I want to scale down the frame whenever I am holding it down (like a click animation) and I want it to scale back when releasing it. With the tap gesture recognizer it seems like I can only do something when I release my finger off the frame.

At the moment I am using this code:

**XAML**

```
<Frame.GestureRecognizers>
       <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Voeding_Tapped" />
</Frame.GestureRecognizers>
```

**C#**

```
void Info_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frame.ScaleTo(0.9, 100);
}
```

With this code, the frame scales down whenever I click and release the frame. How do I make it so that while I am clicking the frame, it scales down, and when I release, it scales back?

Comment: Take a look at this article, it shows you how to create custom renderer to handle custom gestures, one of which is `OnDown` and another `OnLongPress`, bith of which could suit your purpose ... https://arteksoftware.com/gesture-recognizers-with-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 I am not an expert in Xamarin and I find it a bit confusing how everything is in C# rather than XAML. How do I do this with both XAML and C#?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample way not using custom gestures, just using [Composite Animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple#composite-animations) as follow:

**C#**

```
async void Info_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await frame.ScaleTo(0.9, 2000);
    await frame.ScaleTo(1, 2000);
}
```

=================================Update=====================================

If need Long press Gestures ,Creating a custom **Frame**:

```
public class FrameWithLongPress : Frame
{
    public EventHandler LongPressActivated;

    public void HandleLongPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Handle LongPressActivated Event
    }
}
```

**Android** , customing a FrameRenderer (LongPressGestureRecognizerFrameRenderer):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FrameWithLongPress), typeof(LongPressGestureRecognizerFrameRenderer))]
// FrameWithLongPress is created custom frame name in forms, LongPressGestureRecognizerFrameRenderer is renderer name
public class LongPressGestureRecognizerFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
{
    FrameWithLongPress view;

    [Obsolete]
    public LongPressGestureRecognizerFrameRenderer()
    {
        this.LongClick += async (sender, args) => {
            Toast.MakeText(this.Context, "Long press is activated.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            await view.ScaleTo(0.9, 2000);
            await view.ScaleTo(1, 2000);
        };
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            view = e.NewElement as FrameWithLongPress;
        }
    }
}
```

**IOS** , LongPressGestureRecognizerFrameRenderer :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FrameWithLongPress), typeof(LongPressGestureRecognizerFrameRenderer))]
// FrameWithLongPress is created custom frame name in forms, LongPressGestureRecognizerFrameRenderer is renderer name
public class LongPressGestureRecognizerFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
{
    FrameWithLongPress view;
    public LongPressGestureRecognizerFrameRenderer()
    {
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer uiLongPressGesture = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer(new Action(async () => {
            await view.ScaleTo(0.9, 2000);
            await view.ScaleTo(1, 2000);
        }));
        this.AddGestureRecognizer(uiLongPressGesture);
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            view = e.NewElement as FrameWithLongPress;
        }
    }
}
```

**Xaml** using Custom Frame :

```
<local:FrameWithLongPress WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="100" BackgroundColor="BlueViolet"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't go off when holding the button down.

Comment: @Jip1912 Yeah,mistaking your point.If want holding down event , this should use Custom gestures.Then can get long press event. :)

Comment: @Jip1912 I have updated answer . If be helpful , thanks for marking in advance.

Comment: thanks for that! I've never used a custom renderer before so I don't know if I am implementing it the right way. I just made a class in android with your code and another class in the project folder with the first code and changed the XAML after that. However, I am getting the following errors; https://gyazo.com/c176a3ae8df222a8cb61013a5439bb21

Comment: @Jip1912 Maybe you mistake `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FrameWithLongPress), typeof(LongPressGestureRecognizerFrameRenderer))]` before namespace. I will update answer , and show official document for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I was on vacation. I am getting the following errors in `LongPressGestureRecognizerFrameRenderer.cs`: https://gyazo.com/ab15b51ca18d673b1ade00c0e545aa25 (there are no quick actions that fixes these)

Comment: @Jip1912 You missing some using in project.`using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;` Here is my project screenshot:https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwEM6.png App12 is my project namespace .

Comment: Thanks that worked. There's a problem though, cause when I create the custom frame, the page get's really really long. I don't see anything anymore other than the scrollbar, which just changes slightly when I scroll, meaning that the page is really long.

Comment: @Jip1912 Okey, this should be another problem. If this question be solved , you can create another question in SO.Then you can detail explain this problem in another question .If share link here , I will check another question. Last thanks for marking in advance.

Comment: But the problem is really coming from the custom frame, so that should be in this thread right?

Comment: @Jip1912 Due to I don't know other codes in page and your question's title seems not match this question. You can create another question to show image and code .